# Xcode 8.2.1 ,IOS 8 Simulator with crash dyld: Symbol not found: _ASCIIEncoding_GetByteCount_m1396020051

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I am building a game for IOS using unity, but the build crashes. I am using unity version 5.5 and Xcode 8.2.1

> dyld: Symbol not found: _ASCIIEncoding_GetByteCount_m1396020051
>   Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/
>   Expected in: flat namespace
>    in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/

This is my pod file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
install! 'cocoapods', :integrate_targets => false
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'Unity-iPhone' do
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.13'
end
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
 target.build_configurations.each do |config|
   config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
 end
 end
 end
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the missing framework. Kindly check foundation framework is added or not.

```
Make sure you have Foundation framework to your project. (Remove and add it again to be sure).
```

Also clean deep clean the code and run it again.

```
shift + cmd + K
```

Comment: clean and try again. shift + cmd + K

Comment: That's also tried not working while built its showing black screen.

Comment: No i am not getting any error built crashes in simulator

Comment: Try to check in device once.

Comment: same problem in device too

Comment: What is the solutions>?

Comment: i don't know .please help me

Comment: Can you share screen shots which you get it?